# CSS rule not being applied

Tags: css

I know the order of css selectors matters within a style sheet, but does the order of the references to external sheets matter?

I have a page that is referencing 2 sheets. One of the rules in the main sheet is overriding a rule in the other sheet. Rearranging the references hasn't helped. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you check that it's actually being overriden (using Firebug or similar?)

Comment: Please post a minimal test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whack an `!important` after the style you want to enforce.

Example:

```
p.my-style {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample?  perhaps the style is not specific enough to the element.

Comment: I spoke too soon. That did help.

Answer (score 1):

The !important clause following a property is the sure-fire way to have it take precedence over all others, however you can address it in a different way by understanding the selector's specificity. There's a great primer for the concept of CSS selector specificity [here](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/).

Essentially, you will want to make the selector which contains the property that you wish to "win" be much more specific by using ids and a more specific hierarchy of tags/classes/ids

Answer (score 0):

The declaration order is used as a tie breaker when different rules have the same importance, origin (page author, user or user-agent) and specificity. Read section "[6.4.1 Cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order)" of CSS 2.1 for details.

If a rule isn't applying, make sure the selector matches and is of equal or higher specificity than other selectors that match the same element. Examine the element in a good CSS debugger.